# Getting a node with attributes from SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

I am quite the n00b but lately I have been playing with parsing some XML data.  I actually found a nice feature on this site where I can get to a specific node with a specific attribute by doing: docFoo.SelectSingleNode("foo/bar/baz[@name='qux']);  However, the data looks like this:

```
<saving-throws>
    <saving-throw>
        <name>Fortitude</name>
        <abbr>Fort</abbr>
        <ability>Con</ability>
        <modifiers>
            <modifier name="base" value="2"/>
            <modifier name="ability" value="5"/>
            <modifier name="magic" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="feat" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="race" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="familar" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="feature" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="user" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="misc" value="0"/>
        </modifiers>
    </saving-throw>
    <saving-throw>
        <name>Reflex</name>
        <abbr>Ref</abbr>
        <ability>Dex</ability>
        <modifiers>
            <modifier name="base" value="6"/>
            <modifier name="ability" value="1"/>
            <modifier name="magic" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="feat" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="race" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="familar" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="feature" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="user" value="0"/>
            <modifier name="misc" value="0"/>
        </modifiers>
    </saving-throw>
```

And I want to be able to get the node with name=base but for each saving-throw node where childnode "abbr" = xx.  Can I somehow do that in a single SelectSingleNode or am I going to have to stop at saving throw and walk through the rest of the tree?

Comment: Upgrade from 3.5 to 4E and you don't need to worry about those old saving throw values. ;) Seriously though, where's the original XML document? It looks like you meant to link it in "this site" but I don't see the link.

Comment: Nah I messed up the wiki formatting, should be there now.  I have no interest in 4E (DM has a TON of old 3.5 E stuff). :)

Answer (score 7):

This should give you exactly what you want:

```
SelectSingleNode("/saving-throws/saving-throw[abbr = 'Fort']/modifiers/modifier[@name='base']");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this will give you the **modifier** tag who's **saving-throw** ancestor's child **abbr** tag is "Fort"

```
//saving-throw/modifiers/modifier[@name='base' and ../../abbr = "Fort"]
```